# Rewrite rules not working: is a regoluar expression or another language?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm using Rack Rewrite to make some 301 redirect from two website. This is the gem [rack rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) and in documentation there is this example:

```
rewrite %r{/wiki/John_Trupiano(\?.*)?}, '/john$1'
```

I try to write my redirect using regular expression:

```
r301      %r{/(?<=prodotti\/)?.*(?=\/)/},     '/prodotti/$1'
```

But is doesn't work.

Basically I have some url `/prodotti/1996/HTC-One-M8.html` and I need a 301 redirect to `/prodotti/1996`

**Update**

In my website I also have some other routes like

`/prodotti/latest`, `/prodotti/1996`, `/prodotti/all`

I need something that match the ID between the two / / only if the source is something like this `/prodotti/1996/HTC-One-M8.html`

My regex works: `/(?<=prodotti\/)?.*(?=\/)/` but the Gem ask me to store the querystring in a capture group (via (?.*) ) and the to use `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will do that:

`\/prodotti\/([^\/]*)`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/tF9oZ0

Comment: I cannot use this, I have other pages in /prodotti/....

I need to match the ID between / / and the append the ID to prodotti/

Comment: @RobertoPezzali, If I understand you correctly, then this will do exactly that. However, if that is not what you meant, can you please update your question with the new problem and then let me know.

Comment: Updated now, I hope that now the issue is more clear.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali, Is that better? Now the first captured group is the `ID` you wanted.